# Autoresize text to fill fixed size container using HTML only

Tags: html, css

Needing a solution to autoresize text in a fixed sized container. A single word should appear really large filling the container. The longer the string the smaller the font becomes as it resizes to fit on one line.

The code I've found (see below) is almost there but for some reason wraps the text onto a second line. Any suggestions on how I could fix it so no matter how long the string of text it will resize and always be just a single line of text?

Thanks

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    #dynamicDiv
    {
    background: #CCCCCC;
    width: 240px;
    height: 64px;
    font-size: 64px;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function shrink()
    {
        var textSpan = document.getElementById("dynamicSpan");
        var textDiv = document.getElementById("dynamicDiv");

        textSpan.style.fontSize = 64;

        while(textSpan.offsetHeight > textDiv.offsetHeight)
        {
            textSpan.style.fontSize = parseInt(textSpan.style.fontSize) - 1;
        }
    }
</script>

</head>
<body onload="shrink()">
    <div align='center' id="dynamicDiv"><span id="dynamicSpan">Here is a string of text I want on just one line</span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Using HTML, not jQuery"... But that code above does use javascript, not only HTML. So why can't you use jQuery which is pure javascript, if you can obviously use javascript?!?

Comment: What's with the align=center? and why does the solution have to be using HTML when you're already using CSS and JavaScript?

Comment: Also note that more and more pages block such inline script code by their csp policy due to massive vulnerabilities to scripting attacks.

Comment: Sorry guys, I misunderstood jQuery...javascript is obviously ok. I'll be using this for an Objective C program within Xcode so I don't need to worry about scripting attacks etc. Have updated the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

This code works, but I am using a little jQuery, I hope this helps in some way...

```
<style type="text/css">
    #container {
        height:100px;
        background-color:#eeeeee;
        text-align:center;
        font-family:Myriad Pro;
    }
<style>

<div id="container">01234567890123456789</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var w = parseInt($("#container").width());
        var l = parseInt($("#container").html().length);
        var fontSize = ( (w / l) * 2 ) - 2;        
            fontSize = fontSize+'px';

        $("#container").css('font-size', fontSize);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping Armando but this doesn't resize the text. For example, if the text is just "Text" that should fill the size of the container. As the string gets longer the font size should shrink just enough to fit on one line.